# I am not able to print values in editTextField

Tags: android

```
public void calculatePrimeNumbers() {
        int i = 0;        



        while (++i <= UPPER_LIMIT) {

            int i1 = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(i));

            boolean isPrimeNumber = false;

            while (i1 > 1) {

                if ((i != i1) && (i % i1 == 0)) {
                    isPrimeNumber = false;
                    break;
                } else if (!isPrimeNumber) {
                    isPrimeNumber = true;
                }

                --i1;
            }

            if (isPrimeNumber) {
             numDisplay.append(String.valueOf(primeNumberCounter));
             numDisplay.append("\n");
             //  System.out.println(i);
                ++primeNumberCounter;
            }


        }
```

I am not able to print values of prime numbers from 1 to 1000 in editTextfield.

Comment: have you tried debugging using a debugger

Comment: Where you are setting text in EditText?

Comment: Yes when the same code is run in java it works fine but in android

Comment: In if(isPrimeNumber){

Comment: numDisplay.append(String.valueof(primeNumberCounter));

Comment: numDisplay is your Edittext? what is your EditText?

Comment: at first I used setText(String.valueOf(primeNumberCounter)); in that case it didnot worked also

Comment: yes numDisplay is edittext

Comment: Please have a look of my answer. :)

Comment: Kindly show full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this -

```
numDisplay.setText(primeNumberCounter+"");
```

Comment: So working or not?
if not, then what error are you getting.

Comment: if (isPrimeNumber) {
             // numDisplay.setText(primeNumberCounter + "");
             numDisplay.setText( String.valueOf(primeNumberCounter));
             //numDisplay.append(String.valueOf(primeNumberCounter));
            // numDisplay.append("\n");
             //  System.out.println(i);
                ++primeNumberCounter;
            }

Comment: limit for loop is 1000.may be becoz of this I am getting error

Comment: in stack  trace I don't get any error display.sorry limit for loop is 10000

Answer (score 0):

if you are using setText and exception is thrown you need to cast integer to string or for example you want to print "i" value do this

```
 editText.setText(i + "");
```

Comment: still getting the same error .Unfortunately application stoped working

Comment: op has `String.valueOf(primeNumberCounter)`. So that is not going to cause exception

Comment: @ayeshaabdulmajeed post your stack trace.

Comment: unfortunately prime calculation has stopped working is displayed.If I comment edit.setText(primeNumberCounter) exception is not raised.

Comment: @ayeshaabdulmajeed where do you have that in your code? I don't see that at all. Update your code and post stacktrace. comment won't help

Comment: Value for loop limit is 1000 may becoz of this I am getting error